# Mac terminal node REPL output for variable declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, read-eval-print-loop, variable-declaration

In the Mac (OS X 10.13.3) terminal, when I enter the REPL for node (v8.10.0) and enter the following various lines I get the indicated outputs:

```
> let a = 'abc'
undefined

> const b = 'abc'
undefined

> var c = 'abc'
undefined

> d = 'abc'
'abc'
```

Why the difference in output between the first three versus the last one?

I understand that, in ES5 non-strict mode, `var x = 1` and `x = 1` result in different variable scopes, but I suspect that's not the issue here.

I also understand that `d = 'abc'` is no longer a best practice for JavaScript and is not even allowed in, say, ES5 strict mode. However, I'm just trying to understand either the syntactic differences between the lines and/or how the node REPL interprets input. Does this have something to do with statements versus expressions (or definitions or assignments or declarations or...)?

*(I've tried to search StackOverflow, but haven't found the answer in questions entitled ['node.js displays “undefined” on the console'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8457389/5218951) or ['node.js REPL “undefined”
'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10186565/5218951). I also can't find an answer in the [Node.js v8.10.0 Documentation section for REPL](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/repl.html). Searching Google for, say, `node repl "return value"`, etc. also does not help.)*

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35389977/1048572) helps?

Comment: Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43159103/1048572) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30662677/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

The first two (`let` and `const`) are [***LexicalDeclaration***](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations)s. The next (`var`) is a [***VariableStatement***](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2). The last is an [***AssignmentExpression***](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13).

*LexicalDeclaration*s and *VariableStatement*s have no return value. *AssignmentExpression*s have. Details below.

## Details

Beginning with the third, take the `var identifier = expression`, for instance. It is a [***VariableStatement***](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2). Its evaluation semantics are expressed in the spec as below:

> ## Semantics
>
> The production *VariableStatement* : **`var`** *VariableDeclarationList* ; is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate *VariableDeclarationList*.
> 2. Return (normal, **empty**, empty).

Notice the **empty**s in the return of the expression. The same doesn't happen in [assignments (see the *Return* part)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1).

About the [**`let` and `const` declarations**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations), about [their evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> #### 13.3.1.4 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation
>
> *LexicalDeclaration* : *LetOrConst BindingList ;*
>
> 1. Let next be the result of evaluating *BindingList*.
> 2. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-returnifabrupt)(*next*).
> 3. Return [NormalCompletion](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-normalcompletion)(***empty***).

Again, empty (`undefined`) return on normal completion. (Abrupt happens when the variable has already been declared, for example.)

The last one is an [***AssignmentExpression***](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13). It **evaluates to** (returns) a value. For instance, take its simplest form, [**Simple Assignment**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), evaluation specs:

> The production *AssignmentExpression* : *LeftHandSideExpression* =
>   *AssignmentExpression* is **evaluated** as follows:
>
> - 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
>       ...
> - 6. Return *rval*.

Notice the returning of a value.

Comment: In fact statements *do* have result values, which are usually printed on the console - but variable declarations indeed have an `undefined` result.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `for (let i=0; i<1; i++) "hello";` *does* print something on the console - it's still a statement.

Comment: Well, yeah, other statements such as [ExpressionStatement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4), `if`, `while` do have a return value. But `VariableDeclarationList`s don't. (To be exact, they return `undefined` as we all know.)

Comment: @Bergi I have replaced the terms I used with more specific terms, from the spec. Don't know how much I killed the readability of the answer, but at least I hope it is less ambiguous now...

Comment: Thanks for the effort/expertise. Your tl;dr is very helpful. While the spec info is a bit over my head, I can see that the `var` VariableStatement and the `let`/`const` LexicalDeclarations each return something that contains `empty` (presumably leading to the `undefined`) while the AssignmentExpression returns a non-`empty` value, specifically `rval` (from `GetValue(rref)`...just to show you I attempted to follow the links!). Is the following correct: `x = 1` is an assignment expression, is also a statement (in the same way that `42` is) but is not a declaration?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `x = 1` is an [AssignmentExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13) (it matches *LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression*) and, as an Expression (find it down in the [Expressions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.3) list) it can also be used as a [statement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12), more specifically, a [ExpressionStatement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4).

Comment: ...but it is _not_ a declaration?

Comment: I don't think so... See, a [Program](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14) is roughly a sequence of function declarations or statements. And in the [list of what a Statement is](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.4) there's no *VariableDeclaration*. It only appears in the context of  *VariableStatement* (which is a "`var` *VariableDeclarationList*", where a *VariableDeclarationList*  is a list of *VariableDeclaration*).

Comment: So, considering 2 programs: `something; var x = 1; other;` and  `something; x = 1; other;`. In the first, `x = 1` is a [VariableDeclaration](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2), in the second it is an [ExpressionStatement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4)(an [AssignmentExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13)). If you paste the [JavaScript gramar](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pegjs/pegjs/master/examples/javascript.pegjs) in https://pegjs.org/online and write `x = 1`in the input box you'll get a similar result.